# PowerPivot Data Refresh Error: Please try again in a little while

Tags: excel, 2016, reporting-services, powerpivot, data-refresh

I scheduled data refresh on a power pivot but I'm getting this error.

[image]

Here is ULS logs. How can I solve this issue? Any suggestion? What does "Please try again in a little while" means? :/

```
    EXCEPTION: System.InvalidOperationException: Call to Excel Services returned an error. ---> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPClient.Interfaces.ExcelServicesException: Please try again in a little while. ---> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Please try again in a little while.    
 at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)    
 at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.WebServices.ExcelServiceInternal.SaveWorkbookCopy(String sessionId, String workbookPath, WorkbookType workbookType, SaveOptions saveOptions)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.WebServices.ExcelService.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<SaveWorkbookCopy>b__1a(ExcelServiceInternal service, ProxyServiceResult`1 result)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.WebServices.ApiProxy.RunProxyAction[TResult](Action`2 proxyAction, ProxyServiceResult`1 result, Int32 retriesRemaining)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.WebServices.ExcelService.SaveWorkbookCopy(String sessionId, String workbookPath, WorkbookType workbookType, SaveOptions saveOptions, Status[]& status)    
 at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPClient16.ExcelApi.<>c__DisplayClass10.<SaveWorkbookCopy>b__f(ExcelService svc, Status[]& status)    
 at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPClient16.ExcelApi.<>c__DisplayClass13.<Call>b__12(ExcelService e, Status[]& status)    
 at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPClient16.ExcelApi.Call[T](String fileUrl, ExcelServiceCall`1 serviceCall)     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
 at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPClient16.ExcelApi.Call[T](String fileUrl, ExcelServiceCall`1 serviceCall)    
 at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPClient16.ExcelApi.Call(String fileUrl, ExcelServiceCall serviceCall, String methodName, Object[] parameters)    
 at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin16.DataRefresh.DataRefreshService.ProcessingJob(Object parameters)

The diagnostic trace file 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\Logs\PowerPivot_e030a13151b8466e8ad26d769a01fd67.ppdt' was created and will be reported to Microsoft if opted-in to do so. The exception that generated the trace file is: System.InvalidOperationException: Call to Excel Services returned an error. ---> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPClient.Interfaces.ExcelServicesException: Please try again in a little while. ---> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Please try again in a little while.    
 at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)    
 at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.WebServices.ExcelServiceInternal.SaveWorkbookCopy(String sessionId, String workbookPath, WorkbookType workbookType, SaveOptions saveOptions)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.WebServices.ExcelService.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<SaveWorkbookCopy>b__1a(ExcelServiceInternal service, ProxyServiceResult`1 result)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.WebServices.ApiProxy.RunProxyAction[TResult](Action`2 proxyAction, ProxyServiceResult`1 result, Int32 retriesRemaining)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.WebServices.ExcelService.SaveWorkbookCopy(String sessionId, String workbookPath, WorkbookType workbookType, SaveOptions saveOptions, Status[]& status)    
 at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPClient16.ExcelApi.<>c__DisplayClass10.<SaveWorkbookCopy>b__f(ExcelService svc, Status[]& status)    
 at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPClient16.ExcelApi.<>c__DisplayClass13.<Call>b__12(ExcelService e, Status[]& status)    
 at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPClient16.ExcelApi.Call[T](String fileUrl, ExcelServiceCall`1 serviceCall)     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
 at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPClient16.ExcelApi.Call[T](String fileUrl, ExcelServiceCall`1 serviceCall)    
 at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPClient16.ExcelApi.Call(String fileUrl, ExcelServiceCall serviceCall, String methodName, Object[] parameters)    
 at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin16.DataRefresh.DataRefreshService.ProcessingJob(Object parameters).
```

Also there isn't any file at that location.

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\Logs\PowerPivot_e030a13151b8466e8ad26d769a01fd67.ppdt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint 2016 web application config file must be updated. The default value is **250MB** and the report which scheduled data refresh should not exceed this value.

[image]